# Slow Watson Tone Analyzer API response times

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, tone-analyzer

I am running Tone Analyzer through its paces and am getting pretty slow response times via the API - around 500ms per POST request with a text size averaging around 500 chars (uncoded).  Is anyone having faster or slower response times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you still facing this issue ? 
In case you are not using sentence level analysis, then you can disable it to get faster response. Set sentences=false in the API call.

http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/tone-analyzer/api/v3/#post-tone

Comment: thanks - still rather slow but appreciate the improvement.  Still logging in the 500-700ms range for Tone Analyzer, as opposed to 70-80ms for Language Identify and Language Translate.  Are these services in the same location or could it be a latency issue?

Answer (score 0):

We saw a lot of load coming to tone over the weekend. It might be that your requests coincided with our high traffic times.